# Times Ten LOB support

Tags: oracle11g, timesten

I have a passthrough connection in my c# application and I'm trying to do a select on a clob column which is in the database but not in-memory. But I get the following error, any ideas what I'm missing?

> ORA-57000: TT5187: Caching LOBs from Oracle requires using an OCI client library provided by the TimesTen installation, or other versions of OCI client supported by TimesTen. -- file "bdbLob.c", lineno 224, procedure "ttBDbOraLobGetOraIdSnap"

Comment: Well, are you "using an OCI client library provided by the TimesTen installation, or other versions of OCI client supported by TimesTen." ?

Comment: You are right Mat, I had to set the dllpath in the config file to point to the right location to have it working. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the exact steps that you took as an answer? That way people with the same issue will find an answer quickly here, which is what this site is about. That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As to Mat's comment above, I'm posting the solution for this problem. Created an entry in the config file as follows:

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
<settings>
  <add name="DllPath"               value="C:\oracle\bin"/>
  <add name="FetchSize"             value="65536"/>
  <add name="PromotableTransaction" value="promotable"/>
  <add name="StatementCacheSize"    value="10"/>     
</settings>
```

Dllpath is all that is needed to resolve the dll path.